# Optimizing process determining license usage in time

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to find an efficient way to go through a big amount of data to determine how many units are processed at once.
So the data that I am receiving are just simple pairs:
`{timestamp: *, solvetime: *}`
What I need, is to see how many things are processed at each second.

To help you visualize what I mean: here is an example of data that I receive:

```
{{timestamp: 5, solvetime: 3},{timestamp: 7, solvetime: 5},{timestamp: 8, solvetime: 2},{timestamp: 12, solvetime: 10},{timestamp: 14, solvetime: 7}}
```

The chart below should help you understand how it looks in time:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEIhW.png

This is a simple case where the final calculation contains every second, but if the timeframe is much wider I show only 205 different times in this timeframe. E.g. if the time btw the first and the last timestamp is 20500 seconds I would calculate the usage for every second and divide the time into 205 parts - 100 seconds each and show only the second with the highest usage.

What I am doing right now is to iterate through all the pairs of input data and create a map of all the seconds, once I have it I go through this map again to find the highest usage in each time period (of 205 time periods I divide the whole time-frame in) and append it to the map of 205 timestamps.

It's working correctly, but it's very very slow and I feel like there is some better way to do it, a table might be faster but it is still not too efficient is it?

Here is the actual code that does it:

```
// results contain all the timestamps and solvetimes
// Timeframe of the chart
    var start = Math.min.apply(Math, msgDetailsData.results.map((o) => { return o.timestamp; }))
    var end = Math.max.apply(Math, msgDetailsData.results.map((o) => { return o.timestamp; }))

    // map of all seconds in desired range (keys) the values are counter ofprocesses run in a given second
    let mapOfSecondsInRange = new Map();
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      mapOfSecondsInRange.set(i, 0);
    }

    // we go through every proces and add +1 to the value of each second in which the task was active
    for (let element of msgDetailsData.results) {
      var singleTaskStart = element.timestamp - Math.ceil(element.solveTime);
      if (singleTaskStart < start) {
        for (let i = singleTaskStart; i < start; i++) {
          mapOfSecondsInRange.set(i, 0);
        }
        start = singleTaskStart;
      }
      for (let i = singleTaskStart; i < element.timestamp; i++) {
        mapOfSecondsInRange.set(i, mapOfSecondsInRange.get(i) + 1);
      }
    }

    // Preparation for the final map - all the seconds in the range divided into 205 parts. 
    const numberOfPointsOnChart = 205;
    var numberOfSecondsForEachDataPoint = Math.floor((end - start) / numberOfPointsOnChart) + 1;
    var leftoverSeconds = ((end - start) % numberOfPointsOnChart) + 1;
    var highestUsageInGivenTimeframe = 0;
    var timestampOfHighestUsage = 0;
    let mapOfXXXDataPoints = new Map();
    var currentElement = start;
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPointsOnChart; i++) {
      if (leftoverSeconds === 0) {
        numberOfSecondsForEachDataPoint = numberOfSecondsForEachDataPoint - 1;
      }
      if (currentElement <= end) {
        for (let j = 0; j < numberOfSecondsForEachDataPoint; j++) {
          if (j === 0) {
            highestUsageInGivenTimeframe = mapOfSecondsInRange.get(currentElement);
            timestampOfHighestUsage = currentElement;
          }
          else {
            if (mapOfSecondsInRange.get(currentElement) > highestUsageInGivenTimeframe) {
              highestUsageInGivenTimeframe = mapOfSecondsInRange.get(currentElement);
              timestampOfHighestUsage = currentElement;
            }
          }
          currentElement = currentElement + 1;
        }
        mapOfXXXDataPoints.set(timestampOfHighestUsage, highestUsageInGivenTimeframe);
        leftoverSeconds = leftoverSeconds - 1;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can do this with a [running sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total) that increments when a process starts and decrements when a process ends.

Comment: I'm not very clear about what you are exactly trying to achieve. Do you want to know the peak number of problems that are being solved simultaneously? IMHO, The additional data and implementation that you provided, while good, does not help to convey the juice of the problem in a concise and clear way.

Comment: Hmm fair enough, I am not sure what else is not clear, but I did not mention the aim, so my bad:
I want to process this data to create a chart of licence usage in a given timeframe (given by the lowest and the highest timestamp). The chart consists of 205 points (time-frame divided into 205 periods). In each period I put the second with the highest usage on the chart).